# Why can't I return a string from a function which gets a value from Ionic storage?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a method for getting a value from storage that I can use throughout my app. I've created a service and added the function...

```
getValue() {
    this.storage.get('value').then((val) => {
        return val;
    });
}
```

then call it like

```
const value = this.myService.getValue();

console.log('value=' + value);
```

But it doesn't work; `console.log()` just returns `value=[object Promise]`

How can I return the value as a string?

Answer (score 2):

You must understand that `Storage` `get()` method is async, meaning that it return a Promise, not the value directly. That's the reason you need to chain the `.then()` method, right?

When you chain the `.then(...)`, you pass a function as parameter to it:

```
this.storage.get('values').then((value) => { ... });
//                              ^                ^
//                              |                |
//                              --------------------> This is a function
```

This function is a handler for that promise. When you return something from it, it will just transform the promise output. But that `return` will NOT bubble out of the that function.

So your `getValue()` function must also return a Promise:

```
getValue() {
    return this.storage.get('value').then((val) => {
        return val;
    });
}
```

And wherever you use it, you must treat it as a Promise (chain `.then()` to get it value):

```
this.myService.getValue().then((value) => { console.log(value); });
```

Comment: How do I set `value` as a variable so I can use it elsewhere? When doing: `this.api.getValue().then((value) => {let myValue = value;});` then `console.log('myValue='+myValue)` I get `myValue=undefined`

Comment: You can't. Imagine the promisse as a function inside a timer: it will probably run after the remaining of your code, so the variable is empty when your console log runs. that's why you need to keep using promisses all the way. Be prepared for it. Everything on ionic (and many frameworks) is async and will have this behavior.